# ..to confirm that X is employed as an ABC since XZ. Why not "has been employed"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, present-tense

I would like to write a confirmation letter for an employee. I found a template that states the following:

> We hereby confirm that [name, born on, where], is employed as [role]
> since [date]

Why it is not "has been employed", isn't that the proper tense in this case?

Comment: It should be: has been employed. **You are right**. There is a lot of poorly written junk online.

Comment: The template probably allows for the possibility that the person using it either doesn't know or doesn't wish to disclose the ***since [date]*** element. In that case (if you don't include ***since***), the Present Perfect form ("has been employed") would strongly imply ***...but no longer works for us***. And *that* might be an implication that's definitely *not* wanted, so the suggested phrasing of the template might simply be intended to help not-native speakers avoid accidentally giving the wrong impression.

Comment: (I make that suggestion specifically because of the apparent orthographic conventions being used in the template. We usually use square brackets to indicate ***optional*** elements, but in this case they're obviously being used to indicate that ***[date]*** is a "placeholder" rather than actual text. Making it tricky to *also* indicate that the entirety of ***since [date]*** is an "optional" element.)